# Anidar varias tablas para mostrar registros con la fecha mas reciente

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo una duda con una consulta, necesito realizar una consulta que me muestre la fecha mas reciente del alta de un precio de un producto que tiene registro de varios precios con diferentes fechas, solo quiero obtener la fecha mas reciente para cada producto, y para ello tengo las siguientes tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y mi consulta es la siguiente

```
SELECT  hp.id_historico, 
        p.id_producto, 
        p.codigo_producto, 
        p.nomenclatura, 
        p.subnomenclatura, 
        p.clasificacion, 
        p.unidad_medida, 
        p.subcategoria, 
        p.nombre_producto, 
        p.gramaje, 
        p.entrada_salida, 
        p.status_producto, 
        p.stock, 
        p.id_categoria, 
        p.last_code, 
        CONCAT( u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname, ' ', u.user_perfil ) AS USER, 
        m.marca, 
        hp.precio_unitario, 
        hp.iva, 
        hp.precio_venta, 
        hp.fecha 
FROM    h_precio_prod hp, 
        products p, 
        users u, 
        marca m 
WHERE   hp.id_producto = p.id_producto 
AND     hp.user_id = u.user_id 
AND     hp.id_marca = m.id_marca 
GROUP BY hp.id_producto 
ORDER BY hp.fecha DESC
```

el detalle con mi consulta es que me muestra la fecha mas antigua en lugar de la mas reciente y al utilizar una sub consulta me devuelve un error en el formato de la fecha

**Subconsulta**

```
SELECT hp.id_historico, 
        p.id_producto, 
        p.codigo_producto, 
        p.nomenclatura, 
        p.subnomenclatura, 
        p.clasificacion, 
        p.unidad_medida, 
        p.subcategoria, 
        p.nombre_producto, 
        p.gramaje, 
        p.entrada_salida, 
        p.status_producto, 
        p.stock, 
        p.id_categoria, 
        p.last_code, 
        CONCAT( u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname, ' ', u.user_perfil ) AS USER, 
        m.marca, 
        hp.precio_unitario, 
        hp.iva, 
        hp.precio_venta, 
        hp.fecha 
FROM    h_precio_prod hp, 
        products p, 
        users u, 
        marca m 
WHERE   hp.id_producto = (SELECT MAX(hp.fecha) FROM h_precio_prod hp) 
AND     hp.user_id = u.user_id 
AND     hp.id_marca = m.id_marca 
GROUP BY hp.id_producto ORDER BY hp.fecha DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La subconsulta no funciona porque estas comparando el `id_producto` que es de tipo de dato `int` contra la `fecha` con un tipo de dato `datetime`.

Preparé una version mas corta de las tablas relevantes para la solución:

```
create table productos (
id_producto  int not null,
cod_producto  varchar(10) not null,
nombre_producto varchar(64) not null,
stock   int  not null
)

create table historico
(
id_historico int not null,
id_producto int not null,
user_id int not null,
precio_unitario money not null,
fecha   datetime not null,
)
```

Ingresamos data similar:

```
insert into productos values (4350, 'SSM0013-1', 'Botiquin',2)
insert into productos values (4351, 'SAA0208-2', 'Gelatina',20)
insert into productos values (4352, 'SCP0016-1', 'Tamales',2)


insert into historico values (4231, 4351, 1, 02, '01/28/2018')
insert into historico values (4232, 4352, 1, 02, '01/28/2018')
insert into historico values (4233, 4352, 1, 02, '01/29/2018')
insert into historico values (4234, 4352, 2, 02, '01/30/2018')
insert into historico values (4235, 4350, 2, 02, '01/30/2018')
insert into historico values (4236, 4352, 2, 02, '01/31/2018')
insert into historico values (4237, 4352, 2, 02, '02/01/2018')
insert into historico values (4238, 4352, 2, 02, '02/02/2018')
```

Sugiero no tratar de resolver el problema completo, sino separarlo en las consultas más básicas para luego ir a las mas complejas.

La primera parte debería ser obtener la fecha mas reciente de cada producto:

```
select  id_producto id_prod, max(fecha) fecha_reciente
from    historico 
group by id_producto
```

Esto nos devuelve la siguiente información:

```
id_prod     fecha_reciente            
----------- ------------------------- 
4352        2018-02-02 00:00:00.0     
4350        2018-01-30 00:00:00.0     
4351        2018-01-28 00:00:00.0     
(3 rows)Execution time: 0.034 seconds
```

Ahora, comparamos el id y la fecha para obtener el resto de información de la tabla histórica. Tenemos que hacerlo como una subconsulta ya que al hacerlo sobre la query principal, dejaríamos de poder agrupar únicamente por el `id_producto` y por lo tanto ya no obtendríamos la fecha mas reciente:

```
select  his.precio_unitario,
        his.fecha,
        his.user_id
from historico his, 
            (
               select id_producto id_prod, max(fecha) fecha_reciente
               from historico 
               group by id_producto 
            ) as sub_consulta
where his.id_producto = sub_consulta.id_prod
and   his.fecha = sub_consulta.fecha_reciente
```

Esto nos devuelve:

```
precio_unitario       fecha                     user_id     
--------------------- ------------------------- ----------- 
2.0000                2018-02-02 00:00:00.0     2           
2.0000                2018-01-30 00:00:00.0     2           
2.0000                2018-01-28 00:00:00.0     1           
(3 rows)Execution time: 0.035 seconds
```

Y ahora, agregamos al join a la tabla productos:

```
select      prod.id_producto,
            prod.cod_producto,
            prod.nombre_producto,
            prod.stock,
            his.precio_unitario,
            his.fecha,
            his.user_id
from historico his, 
      (
            select id_producto id_prod, max(fecha) fecha_reciente
            from historico 
            group by id_producto 
      ) as sub_consulta,
        productos   prod
where his.id_producto = sub_consulta.id_prod
and   his.fecha = sub_consulta.fecha_reciente
and    prod.id_producto = his.id_producto
```

Para obtener la información que deseamos:

```
id_producto cod_producto nombre_producto                                                  stock       precio_unitario       fecha                     user_id     
----------- ------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------- ------------------------- ----------- 
4352        SCP0016-1    Tamales                                                          2           2.0000                2018-02-02 00:00:00.0     2           
4350        SSM0013-1    Botiquin                                                         2           2.0000                2018-01-30 00:00:00.0     2           
4351        SAA0208-2    Gelatina                                                         20          2.0000                2018-01-28 00:00:00.0     1           
(3 rows)Execution time: 0.03 seconds
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabas de despejar mi duda, ya vi cual fue mi error, y es que al comparar en la posision del WHERE historico.fecha = (SELECT MAX(fecha) FROM historico) ...    solo me devolvia un solo regsitro de la consulta en lugar de darme un regsitro por producto con la fecha mas reciente, garcias